# Starting an Extension in Alfresco 4.0

Tags: alfresco

I want to run the extension
("C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\scheduled-action-services-context.xml)

I have made some changes in it, however when I restart the server I don't see it in my log files.

Do I need something else to start it.

EDIT:

Here is the content of my scheduled action services:

```
   <!--
Define the model factory used to generate object models suitable for use with freemarker templates. 
-->
<bean id="templateActionModelFactory" class="org.alfresco.repo.action.scheduled.FreeMarkerWithLuceneExtensionsModelFactory">
    <property name="serviceRegistry">
        <ref bean="ServiceRegistry"/>
    </property>
</bean>

   <!--
Execute the script /Company Home/Record Management/testscript.js
-->
<bean id="runScriptAction" class="org.alfresco.repo.action.scheduled.SimpleTemplateActionDefinition">
    <property name="actionName">
        <value>script</value>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterTemplates">
        <map>
            <entry>

                <key>
                    <value>script-ref</value>
                </key>
                <!-- Note that as of Alfresco 4.0, due to a  Spring upgrade, the FreeMarker ${foo} entries must be escaped --> 
                <value>\$\{selectSingleNode('workspace://SpacesStore', 'lucene', 'PATH:"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:scripts/cm:send_mail.js"' )\}</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="templateActionModelFactory">
        <ref bean="templateActionModelFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dictionaryService">
        <ref bean="DictionaryService"/>
    </property>
    <property name="actionService">
        <ref bean="ActionService"/>
    </property>
    <property name="templateService">
        <ref bean="TemplateService"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--
```

Run the script every minute - select the single node company home that is not used ...
    -->
    
        
            UNTIL_FIRST_FAILURE
        
        
            IGNORE
        
        
            
        
        
            
        
        
            lucene
        
        
            
                workspace://SpacesStore
            
        
        
            +@ia\:fromDate:\$\{luceneDateRange(now, \"P10D\")\} AND +PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:prova/cm:calendar//*"</value>-->
         +PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:valdel/cm:calendar//*" AND +@ia\:fromDate:[NOW TO MAX]

```
    </property>
    <property name="cronExpression"> 
        <value>0 * 8 * * ?</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jobName">
        <value>jobD</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jobGroup">
        <value>jobGroup</value>
    </property>
    <property name="triggerName">
        <value>triggerD</value>
    </property>
    <property name="triggerGroup">
        <value>triggerGroup</value>
    </property>
    <property name="scheduler">
        <ref bean="schedulerFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="actionService">
        <ref bean="ActionService"/>
    </property>
    <property name="templateActionModelFactory">
        <ref bean="templateActionModelFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="templateActionDefinition">
        <ref bean="runScriptAction"/> <!-- This is name of the action (bean) that gets run -->
    </property>
    <property name="transactionService">
        <ref bean="TransactionService"/>
    </property>
    <property name="runAsUser">
        <value>System</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

AND WHEN I CHECK THE STDOUT, I'M SEEEING THIS ERROR:

2012-03-30 11:00:00,230  ERROR [freemarker.runtime] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-8] Template processing error: "No nodes selected"

No nodes selected

### The problematic instruction:

### ==> ${selectSingleNode('workspace://SpacesStore', 'lucene', 'PATH:"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:scripts/cm:send_mail.js"' )} [on line 1, column 1 in string://fixed]

### Java backtrace for programmers:

freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: No nodes selected
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.scheduled.FreeMarkerWithLuceneExtensionsModelFactory$QueryForSingleNodeFunction.exec(FreeMarkerWithLuceneExtensionsModelFactory.java:180)

Could someone explain me this.. I have written a cron to run every 8 minutes but its not working

Comment: Can you show the content of your scheduled-action-services-context.xml file?

Comment: Looks like the context file is running just fine, but you've given it the wrong search query to find your node! Can you double check the search path?

Answer (score 1):

"Run the extension" doesn't really make sense. When you start Tomcat, the Alfresco web application will load that Spring configuration file automatically because it is on the classpath (assuming you have set up your shared classloader correctly) and it ends in "context.xml". If you aren't seeing something you expect in the log files, check log4j.properties to make sure you have a logger set. If all else fails, use a remote debugger like Eclipse and set a breakpoint in one of the Java classes referred to by your context file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your error is because of https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-9981